# Insert Performance dropped suddenly in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis, insert, buffer

I have a SSIS package which imports data to SQL Server. Earlier it took me around 2 hours to complete but now it takes 4.5 hours.

I inspected and found some of the dft's were taking much time even though there is no surge in data count

Would love to know what are the factors could affect insert performance

Following are my findings,

1. I found that buffer size and row count for each table on dft is not
   set correctly. All dft's are using generic numbers for those
   settings. So have to find optimal number for each dft table.
2. Suspecting that index fragmentation caused slowness

Please suggest some check list to validate.

Comment: Has the size of the target tables increased significantly over time?

Comment: we implemented partition on table and deleting day-30 data on daily basis. So I see no significant increase in size

Comment: Partitioning can actually cause it to slow down rather than speed up, unless you use partition switching

Comment: any links learn  partition switch ?  partition switch , are you suggesting it for inserting ?